# not getting data from SQL to JTable in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to get data from my database. However when the program is getting the data from the `resultSet`, it doesn't seem to be getting anything and at the end `data[][]` is all `null`. When debugging, I noticed that the Result r `currentRow` is always `-1` throughout the while loop and it isn't changing. I don't know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

The code :

```
//GET INFORMATION FROM THE TABLE
public void view(String table, Connection conn) {

    try {

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE  name  LIKE '%" + name + "%';");
        ResultSet r = statement.executeQuery();

        data = new String[rows][column];
        int j = 0;
        ResultSetMetaData info = (ResultSetMetaData)r.getMetaData();

        x = new String[column];
        for(int i = 0; i < column; i++)
            x[i] = info.getColumnName(i + 1);

        r.beforeFirst();
        while(r.next()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < column; i++)
                data[j][i] = r.getString(x[i]);
            j++;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

}
```

Comment: I would leave out `r.beforeFirst();` as an experiment. And do `r.getString(i + 1);` as `getColumnName/getColumnLabel` is not always that straight-forward

Comment: that actually fixed, thanks alot.